# POST request becomes GET in Cypress while running the test

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, automated-tests, cypress

I'm writing an automated test with Cypress and I need to get the access token generated by an API,

My problem is that I have a post request that generates this token but when I run the test in Cypress, that request shows as GET request and generates nothing.

What should I do?

Comment: You should check one more time to make sure that you call POST method, not GET :|

cy.request(method, url, body)

Comment: Add your cy.intercept code along with the network requests in order to help you.